# Error Consulta Mysql entre distintas versiones

Tags: mysql

Saludos tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT 
    ventas_venta.id, 
    clientes_cliente.nombres, 
    clientes_cliente.ruc, 
    empresa_secuenciadisponible.numero_secuencia AS secuencia, 
    ventas_venta.subtotal, 
    ventas_venta.iva, 
    ventas_venta.descuento, 
    ventas_venta.total, 
    ventas_venta.tipo_pago, 
    ventas_venta.nro_trasferencia, 
    ventas_venta.secuencia_id, 
    ventas_venta.fecha 
FROM 
    ventas_venta 
    LEFT JOIN clientes_cliente ON ventas_venta.cliente_id = clientes_cliente.id 
    LEFT JOIN empresa_secuenciadisponible ON ventas_venta.secuencia_id = empresa_secuenciadisponible.id 
GROUP BY 
    secuencia
```

dicho query funciona bien con la versión:

```
14.14 Distrib 5.6.41
```

ahora bien el mismo query pero con la versión :

```
15.1 Distrib 5.5.60
```

tan solo me muestra 1 resultado, cuando deberían ser 7, ambas base de datos tienen los mismos registros, mismos campos, mismo datos.

Quiza varia algo entre cada version que este afectando el query gracias de ante mano..!!

Comment: Exactamente. Varia que el group by en mysql no estaba standard como en todas las bases de datos. y seguramente en tu segunda version, se arreglo ya que mysql arreglo como tratar los group by y los estandarizo a como esta en todas las bases de datos.

Comment: entiendo y entonces debo desactivar el mode strict  de mysql en la nueva version ?...para de momento evadir este error

Comment: No. En realidad deberias dejar el modo strict, y hacer el query como corresponde. Por desgracia, el query que vos pensas que esta bien, el motor no asegura que siempre devuelva los campos que vos pensas que tiene que devolver. Podes volver atras, pero la recomendacion seria hacer el query como corresponde

Comment: pero @gbianchi de hecho la versión donde la funciona es inferior a la versión donde no le funciona; para lo que le mencionas no debería ser al revés?

Comment: Nop.. Antes estaba strict off por defecto. Antes, te dejaba hacer trampa. Ahora esta strict on por defecto.

Comment: con respecto a "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" en la version mas actual "15.1" esta desactivado dicho modo dado que en sql_mode esta ""

Comment: pero en la version anterior "14.14" esta habilitado el modo "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"

Comment: No se tanto como para decirte cual de los strict mode que tiene te esta afectando. Pero si se, que ese query no es ansi, y por lo tanto es probable que ese sea el problema.

Comment: @gbianchi y como podria hacer dicho query de esa manera que mencionas por donde deberia empezar gracias..de antemano

Comment: Deberias estudiar como debe funcionar un group by. en un group by, todos los campos por los que se agrupa deben estar en el group by, y el resto de los campos deben ser una funcion de agregacion (sum, max, min, etc). Si necesitas agregar campos, tenes que hacerlo despues utilizando esa query como entrada.